# coverting shape-files into text files using Arcmap

Tags: file, gis, shapes

i would like to ask how is it possible to convert shapefile into .txt (text file) using Arcmap 10??? i want to convert my shapefiles data to text so as to save them as UTF-8
is this possible? 
and if this possible how can i convert it back to shapefiles?
thanx

Answer (score 1):

1. Right click on the shapefile you want to convert in the "Layers" menu select "Open Attribute Table"
2. Once you have your data table open in front of you click on the "Table Options" button at the top left. Click "Export"
3. Make sure to select the "export all records" radio button (should be the default unless you have some records selected)
4. Browse to the directory where you want to save the data and once there change the "Save As" format to "Text File."

Once you do the conversion you should be able to add the text file back into your project as you would any other data table (using the 'plus' button for adding any kind of data) and then do a Join (Right click on your layer, select "Joins and Relates->Join", and follow the wizard) operation to attach it back to your original shapefile. 
What is somewhat less clear to me is whether the ancient .dbf structure of shapefile data tables will know what to do with your UTF-8 but that wasn't your question...

Comment: O.k Thanks alot :) one more question, what you described above, is it a good way to save my shapefiles as UTF-8 because my files contains some fields with special characters (arabic) and it doesnot show probably when i use them in my application (am using opentripplanner application to build a street network from shapefiles data) well after i did that still the street names in arabic doesnot show the prober way? is there any approach i should take to save my shapefiles as UTF-8 ???? thnx